# Why is Popen not working for espeak-ruby in my programme?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, popen, espeak

I installed [espeak-ruby](https://github.com/dejan/espeak-ruby) using Bundle, but when I call it in my programme (insult.rb), it throws the following error.

```
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/espeak-ruby-1.1.0/lib/espeak/voice.rb:17:in `popen': No such file or directory - espeak --voices (Errno::ENOENT)
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/espeak-ruby-1.1.0/lib/espeak/voice.rb:17:in `all'
    from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/espeak-ruby-1.1.0/lib/espeak.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from insult.rb:3:in `require'
    from insult.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

This is my gemfile (generated using `bundle init`):

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

source "https://rubygems.org"
gem "espeak-ruby", require: "espeak"

# gem "rails"
```

These are the lines I use to access espeak-ruby in insult.rb:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'espeak'
```

How do I fix this error? I tried reinstalling espeak-ruby and its dependencies. I'm a Ruby newbie, please ask if you need any other details or clarification.

Comment: espeak-ruby is a wrapper library around the espeak program. This program needs to be installed on your computer too. See the documentation at https://github.com/dejan/espeak-ruby#installing-dependencies

Comment: @HolgerJust I tried installing both the dependencies using gem and bundle, but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Well, as written you need the `espeak` and `lame` command line tools. Those have to be installed in addition the the gem. As you appear to use Windows, you may use binaries from e.g. [espeak.sourceforge.net](https://espeak.sourceforge.net/download.html) for espeak and possibly from [rarewares.org](https://www.rarewares.org/mp3-lame-bundle.php) for lame (or some other source). As the `espeak-ruby` gem does not appear to be actively tested on Windows, your mileage may vary though...